# QDockWidgets and QLayouts

Tags: python, pyqt

I've just came across `QDockWidgets`. And I am blown away with the flexibility these widgets offer. But it appears they do require a proper planning ahead.

I put a simple example here:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        mainWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)        

        DockA = QtGui.QDockWidget('DockA')   
        DockB = QtGui.QDockWidget('DockB')   

        mainLayout.addWidget(DockA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(DockB)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = GUI()
    dialog.show() 
    dialog.raise_()       
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

First I am subclassing `QMainWindow`. Then `QWidget` is created. Then assigning it as central via `.setCentralWidget()`. Next `QVBoxLayout()` is created and set to mainWidget.
Now creating DockA and DockB. Dialog shows up. But docks are not movable. 
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to put the dock widgets into a layout? The QMainWindow already has docking areas readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation:

```
QDockWidget provides the concept of dock widgets, also know as tool palettes or
utilitywindows. Dock windows are secondary windows placed in the
"dock widget area" around the central widget in a QMainWindow
```

Please refer to the *detailed description* [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html) and an example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html). It is in C++ but you can get an idea of how to do things.

Comment: My impression is that this answer is too generic and does not specifically respond to the question especially how to make the docks in the example movable or why they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `addDockWidget` method of `QMainWindow` to get fully functional movable dock windows.

Example:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QLabel('MainWidget'))

window.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, QtGui.QDockWidget('DockA'), QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
window.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, QtGui.QDockWidget('DockB'), QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```